# В чем разница между неупорядоченным и упорядоченным словарем?

Tags: python, словари, терминология

Что означает упорядоченный словарь? В чем разница между неупорядоченным и упорядоченным словарем?

Comment: Здесь хорошо описано - https://silentsokolov.github.io/python-37-ordered-dict

Answer (score 2):

Структура данных называется упорядоченной, если элементы хранятся в ней в том же порядке, что и были добавлены.

С версии Python 3.7 словари являются упорядоченной структурой данных за счёт дополнительного списка, который сохраняет порядок добавленных ключей.

```
dct = {}
dct['1'] = 'first'
dct['2'] = 'second'
dct['1'] = 'still first'
for key in dct :
    print(key)  # 1 2
```

Также в Python в модуле `collections` существует `OrderedDict` (упорядоченный словарь), который был реализован ещё тогда, когда словари были неупорядоченными, но даже сейчас для ряда задач его стоит использовать в приоритете над встроенным словарем согласно тексту [Zen of Python](https://peps.python.org/pep-0020/) - явное лучше чем неявное.

```
from collections import OrderedDict

dct = OrderedDict()
dct['1'] = 'first'
dct['2'] = 'second'
dct['1'] = 'still first'
for key in dct :
    print(key)  # 1 2
```